# Telerik DevCraft Complete or DevExpress DXperience

Tags: telerik, dxperience

I have doubts which the package controls is generally better, in terms of functionality, ease of use, support for MVVM, much more "more important" control (Web Controls, ASP.NET MVC controls, Controls for mobile application) in terms of technologies that are the most popular. The most essential of controls are: grid and master-detail grids, combo box (with many items), autocomplete, layout of controls. What are your experiences in the use of the above components? Thank you.

Comment: 1. You didn't ask a question, and 2) SO isn't really the place to solicit for opinions.

Comment: What do You mean? Thanks.

Comment: You didn't ask anything, and appear to be looking for our opinions on which is the better package.  That's not a good fit for StackOverflow.